# Calculating auto covariance in pandas

Tags: pandas, autocorrelation

Following on the answer provided by @pltrdy, in this threat:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164416/14744492

How do you convert the `pandas.Series.autocorr()`, which calculates lag-N (default=1) autocorrelation on Series, into autocovariances?

Sadly the command `pandas.Series.autocov()`is not implemented in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `.autocorr(k)` calculates is the (Pearson) correlation coefficient for lag *k*. But we know that, for a series *x*, that coefficient for lag *k* is:

```
\rho_k = \frac{Cov(x_{t}, x_{t-k})}{Var(x)}
```

Then, to get autocovariance, you multiply autocorrelation by the variance:

```
def autocov_series(x, lag=1):
    return x.autocorr(x, lag=lag) * x.var()
```

Note that `Series.var` uses ddof of 1 by default so `N - 1` divides the sample variance where `N == s.size` (and you'd get an unbiased estimate for the population variance).